# Extract the string from string in Java

Tags: java, string-parsing

I have this string in Java:

```
String str = "-High Upload Observed|High| eventId=285475664495 MMTT type=2  mrt=1482650158658 in=104858769 out=104858769 sessionId=0 generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= modelConfidence=0 severity=0";
```

From the above string I need output be like

```
eventId=285475664495 MMTT 
type=2 
mrt=1482650158658
in=104858769 
out=104858769 
sessionId=0 
generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= 
modelConfidence=0 
severity=0
```

Comment: "can someone help me" => Of course, we can. Show us your code, tell us where it fails to get your expected output, and we will willingly help you to correct it.

Comment: `String str = "-High Upload Observed|High| eventId=285475664495 MMTT type=2 mrt=1482650158658 in=104858769 out=104858769 sessionId=0 generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= modelConfidence=0 severity=0"`

need to extract the attributes 

`output :


eventId=285475664495 MMTT 
type=2 
mrt=1482650158658
in=104858769 
out=104858769 
sessionId=0 
generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= 
modelConfidence=0 
severity=0`

Comment: @Mohan Better update the question and clearly mention what are thing that are going to be same in the string (if any)

Comment: @Mohan do you really need MMTT at the end of the first?

Comment: yes that goes with the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string into array by `|`, get the third element and remove everything after last space;

```
String s = "Office|High| eventId=285469322819 MMTT type=2";
s = s.split("\\|")[2].trim().replaceAll("[^ ]*$", "").trim();
```

EDIT:

Based on what OP given in the comment and assuming 'type` is always the third word.

```
str = str.split("\\|")[2].replaceAll("type.*", "").trim() ;
```

EDIT 2: Requirement changed again:

```
String str = "-High Upload Observed|High| eventId=285475664495 MMTT type=2 mrt=1482650158658 in=104858769 out=104858769 sessionId=0 generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\\=\\= modelConfidence=0 severity=0\" output : eventId=285475664495 MMTT type=2 mrt=1482650158658 in=104858769 out=104858769 sessionId=0 generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\\=\\= modelConfidence=0 severity=0";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^ ]+=[^ ]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str.split("\"")[0]);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

produces:

```
eventId=285475664495
type=2
mrt=1482650158658
in=104858769
out=104858769
sessionId=0
generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\=
modelConfidence=0
severity=0
```

I admit `MMTT` is missing in the first one, but oh well.

Comment: String str = "-High Upload Observed|High| eventId=285475664495 MMTT type=2 mrt=1482650158658 in=104858769 out=104858769 sessionId=0 generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= modelConfidence=0 severity=0"



output :


eventId=285475664495 MMTT 
type=2 
mrt=1482650158658
in=104858769 
out=104858769 
sessionId=0 
generatorID=3+ACVIFkBABCAA951mZ0UyA\=\= 
modelConfidence=0 
severity=0"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex pattern that keeps the `MMTT` part as well:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^ =]+)=([^ ]+(?: +[^ =]+(?= |$))*)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

You can also use `group(1)` and `group(2)` to get the key and value.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the id like this :

```
String str = "Office|High| eventId=285469322819 MMTT type=2";
eventId = str.split("eventId=")[1].split("type")[0].trim();
```